# sleep, screensaver and Filevault

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, imac, sleep-wake, password

I am mystified: first, I have an iMac and a MBP, both running mountain lion. In System Preferences > Security > General > Require Password after sleep or screensaver, I can adjust the time to 4 hours on the iMac, but it goes only as far as one hour on the MBP.

To further complicate the matter, when I turn on File Vault, the checkbox for this option disappears on the MBP, so I can't totally disable it, but everything remains the same on the iMac. What exactly is going on here?
I really want to disable this feature on the MBP, and I'd really appreciate if someone in the know can show me how to achieve that.

Comment: I don't want to enable FileVault, but does `defaults write com.apple.screensaver askForPassword -bool false` or `defaults write com.apple.screensaver askForPasswordDelay -int 14400` (and restarting) have any effect?

Comment: i first went into system preferences and set requires password to immediately so i don't have to wait a long time to see the result. then i used the first command, it had no effect. then i tried the second one but changed the number to 300 so i can see the result sooner...no luck with that one, either.

Comment: What outputs: `defaults read com.apple.screensaver`?